# How to count decimals of an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-accuracy

I want to know how many decimals an input has to then use that information to aproximate the result of an operation to the same number of decimals. For example:

```
example = float(input('n '))
```

Imagine the input is 1.99, how do I obtain the number of decimals (2) to then use it?

Comment: If the user types “3.100”, do you want to use three digits after the decimal point? Read the input as a string and count the digits after the decimal point before converting it to floating-point.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple hack to it.

```
dec = len(str(example).split('.')[1])
```